# How to find the inverse of this Block Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the inverse of this matrix:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
E_p & A & 0 \\
0&E_q & B \\
0 &0 &E_r
\end{pmatrix}
\in GL_{p+q+r}(K)$

$GL$= General linear group

$K$= field

$E_r, E_p, E_q$ = identity matrix

$A, B$ = matrices

---

I tried to look at the special case $p=q=r=1$ and get

$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-A&1 & 0 \\
AB &-B &1
\end{pmatrix}
\in GL_{p+q+r}(K)$

Is this right? How can I generalise this?

Comment: As long as you’re careful to keep things in the right order when multiplying, you can pretty much manipulate block matrices as if the blocks were scalars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using block row operations, we have
$$
\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
      E_p & A & 0& E_p & 0 & 0\\
      0 & E_q & B& 0 & E_q & 0\\
      0 & 0 & E_r& 0 & 0 & E_r
    \end{array} 
\right]\to\\
\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
      E_p & A & 0& E_p & 0 & 0\\
      0 & E_q & 0& 0 & E_q & -B\\
      0 & 0 & E_r& 0 & 0 & E_r
    \end{array} 
\right]\to\\
\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
      E_p & 0 & 0& E_p & -A & AB\\
      0 & E_q & 0& 0 & E_q & -B\\
      0 & 0 & E_r& 0 & 0 & E_r
    \end{array} 
\right]\to
$$
the matrix on the right is the inverse

Comment: Can u please explain how you get this eliminations little but more?

Comment: For example: to get from the first line to the second, I multiply on the left by $$\pmatrix{E_p\\&E_q&-B\\ && E_r}$$
then use block-matrix multiplication

Answer (score 1):

You can verify yourself

$$\begin{pmatrix} E_p & -A & A B \\ 0 & E_q & - B \\ 0 & 0 & E_r \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} E_p & A & 0 \\ 0 & E_q &  B \\ 0 & 0 & E_r \end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix} E_p & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & E_q & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & E_r \end{pmatrix}$$